# Как передавать переменные контроллеру методом POST? Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2

Задача:
Указываем в форме количество -> передаем это количество в другой контроллер -> вызываем оплату робокассы -> робокасса возвращает success -> записываем это количество в базу данных.
Не могу разобраться как передать значения формы в другой контроллер. Если передавать в родной, то все работает. А наоборот нет.
И еще, как передать success в контроллер? Как он его принимает?

UPD.

Я создаю форму, вывожу ее на экран в twig

```
public function donutAction(Request $request, $donut_success = 0){
//Создаем форму
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($donut)
            //->add('id_server', 'integer', array('label' => 'Выберите ваш сервер'))
            ->add('sum','integer', array('label' => 'Количество шариков'))
            ->add('id_server', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Выберите ваш сервер',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default'),
                'required' => false,
                'class'  => 'M4MinecraftBundle:Mc_server',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $ems_select) use($id_user){
                    return $ems_select->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.id_user IN (:id_user)')
                        ->setParameter('id_user', $id_user);},
                'property'=> 'name'
            ))
            ->getForm();
}
```

После этого при нажатии на SUBMIT я перехожу на функцию другого контроллера

```
  public function indexAction($sum){

}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы эта функция принимала значение 'sum' из формы, которую я отправил ей?

```
$sum=$_REQUEST['sum'];
```

Не работает. `$request->getData` тоже пробовал.
Есть еще `$form->bind($request);`. Он у меня работает в одном контроллере, но в этом нет.

Comment: Намного лучше, когда в вопросе указывается часть кода с которой возникла проблема. Могу предположить, что у формы необходимо всего лишь изменить атрибут action.

Comment: Нет, у формы action как раз стоит на новый контроллер. Я просто не знаю как этим контроллером принять значения формы.
Допустим в форме у меня есть значение sum.
Я пишу функцию public function indexAction($sum) { /*код работы с sum */}
Я не могу работать с sum, так как он его не видит. Пробовал делать через $form->getData(); Но не очень понял как нужно делать это правильно

Comment: Всегда можно получить значения через $_POST или $_GET массивы. Конкретнее я не могу ответить, так как нет кода.

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз вопрос. Я его изменил

Comment: А документацию по обработке форм не пробовали смотреть:
[Symfony 2 Формы](http://symfony-gu.ru/documentation/ru/html/book/forms.html)?

Comment: Пробовали. По ней и сделали на одном контроллере обработку. 
Вопрос: как сделать обработку на другом контроллере? Он же не знает ничего про $form

Comment: Заново написать в новом контролере такой же код `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($donut)...` и потом выполнить привязку `$form->bindRequest($request);`. Там же показан пример обработки отправки формы в документации. Ну и принимать вы должны не `$sum`, а `Request $request` и потом после привязки через `$donut->sum` получать значение. Должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, формы лучше обрабатывать в том же контроллере, в котором Вы готовите их вывод. Это общепринятая практика в Symfony. Она позволяет вам не дублировать код формы в двух разных контроллерах.

Если же Вам все же нужно решить свою проблему таким образом, тогда Вам следует [вынести форму в отдельный класс](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes). После чего генерировать форму для вывода в одном контроллере и использовать эту же форму для обработки в другом. Обрабатывать форму следует следующим образом:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $donut = new Donut();
    $form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $donut);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($donut);
        $em->flush();
    }

    // Делать дальше все, что вздумается
}
```

`$form->isSubmitted()` здесь используется исключительно ради эстетического удовольствия. Код в таком случае становится более наглядным и понятным. Это условие повторно проверится в `$form->isValid()`, но зато оно позволяет программисту, читающему код понять, что форма была отправлена без всяких проверок на метод POST или присутствие в запросе имени формы, все это не для контроллера, код становится более понятным.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вопрос стоит не в том как обработать форму в другом контроллере, а как получить POST данные в другом контроллере.

Это реализуется довольно просто:

```
public function indexAction(\Symfony\Compoment\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
{
    // Получаем переданные из формы данные
    $post_data = $request->request->all();
}
```

В этом случае валидация данных ложится на вас. Как сделать валидацию массива можно почитать здесь:

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050240/how-can-i-validate-array-keys-using-symfony-validation
```

Также я бы вам порекомендовал отделять логику в независимые сервисы, а форму перенести в отдельный класс.
В этом случае вам не понадобится отдельный контроллер, вы в основной получаете данные и передаете их в сервис после валидации.